# Proof related to matrix with if and only if condition

Tags: matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are matrices such that $AB$ and $BA$ are defined. Prove that
$$(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+2AB\quad\text{if and only if}\quad AB=BA.$$
Someone help me with this.

Comment: Note these hypotheses imply $A$ and $B$  are square matrices of the same dimension.

Comment: The hypothesis actually doesn't imply that, @Bernard

Comment: @Bernard, no it does not imply that. What it tells us is that if A is of $n\times m$, then B must be of $m\times n$.

Comment: It implies that $AB$ and $BA$ are square matrices.

Comment: If you want to add $A$ and $B$, they must have the same size. And if you want to square a matrix it must be… square.

Answer (score 1):

Using the correct formula for matrix multiplication, we have
$$(A+B)^2=(A+B)(A+B)=A^2+AB+BA+B^2.$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}
(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+2AB &\iff A^2+AB+BA+B^2=A^2+B^2+2AB \\
&\iff AB+BA=2AB \\
&\iff BA=AB.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Suggest to address the meaningfulness of such equations considering the possibility of nonsquare matrices.